# C++ Event (Focus) Handling

Tags: c++, event-handling, wxwidgets, wxtextctrl

### Due to comments I added the following code

(in BasicPanel)

```
Connect(CTRL_ONE, wxEVT_KILL_FOCUS, (wxObjectEventFunction)&BasicPanel::OnKillFocus);
Connect(CTRL_TWO,wxEVT_KILL_FOCUS, (wxObjectEventFunction)&BasicPanel::OnKillFocus);
Connect(CTRL_THREE, wxEVT_KILL_FOCUS, (wxObjectEventFunction)&BasicPanel::OnKillFocus);
Connect(CTRL_FOUR, wxEVT_KILL_FOCUS, (wxObjectEventFunction)&BasicPanel::OnKillFocus);
Connect(CTRL_FIVE, wxEVT_KILL_FOCUS, (wxObjectEventFunction)&BasicPanel::OnKillFocus);
```

(enums)

```
    CTRL_NAME = wxID_HIGHEST + 5, // 6004
    CTRL_ADDRESS = wxID_HIGHEST + 6, // 6005
    CTRL_PHONENUMBER = wxID_HIGHEST + 7, // 6006
    CTRL_SS = wxID_HIGHEST + 8, // 6007
    CTRL_EMPNUMBER = wxID_HIGHEST + 9 // 6008
```

(The OnKillFocus Function - the declaration is included as suggested)

```
void BasicPanel::OnKillFocus(wxFocusEvent& event) {
    switch (event.GetId()) {
        case 6004:
            ...
            break;
                ...    ...     ...
    }
```

**All of these added to the code do nothing when the user changes focus on which text box they are using...**

---

Q1:I am using wxWidgets (C++) and have come accost a problem that i can not locate any help. I have created several `wxTextCtrl` boxes and would like the program to update the simple calculations in them when the user 'kills the focus.' I could not find any documentation on this subject on the wxWidgets webpage and Googling it only brought up wxPython. The two events i have found are: `EVT_COMMAND_KILL_FOCUS - EVT_KILL_FOCUS` for neither of which I could find any snippet for. Could anyone give me a short example or lead me to a page that would be helpful?

Q2:Would i have to create an event to handle the focus being killed for each of my 8 `wxTextCtrl` boxes? In the case that i have to create a different event: How would i get each event to differentiate from each other? I know i will have to create new wxID's for each of the `wxTextCtrl` boxes but how do I get the correct one to be triggered?

```
class BasicPanel : public wxPanel { ...     
    wxTextCtrl* one;
    wxTextCtrl* two;
    wxTextCtrl* three;
    wxTextCtrl* four; ... }
```

Comment: I found the problem... see the comment to my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, first off, here is the code to put in your `BasicPanel` class:

```
void OnKillFocus(wxFocusEvent& event);
```

Then add the following to the end of your `BasicPanel` constructor:

```
Connect(ID_TEXTCTRL,
        wxEVT_KILL_FOCUS ,
        (wxObjectEventFunction)&BasicPanel::OnKillFocus);
```

You will need to repeat the above code for each text control and replace `ID_TEXTCTRL` with the actual ID of the controls.

Then the code below will get called whenever one of the controls loses focus.

```
void BasicPanel::OnKillFocus(wxFocusEvent& event)
{
    // code goes here...
}
```

To determine the ID of the control that *generated* the event within `OnKillFocus`, you can use the following:

```
event.GetId()
```

Comment: After adding the suggested changes... nothing happens any different.

Comment: @Walter: Okay, I figured it out: you need to call `Connect` on the *text control*. So the 'Connect' line above would be changed to `TextCtrl->Connect(....);` where TextCtrl is the pointer to the text control.

Comment: This works, but the callback doesn't seem bound to the BasicPanel instance. The `this` pointer is garbage.