# wxWidgets event focus textcontrol

Tags: events, wxwidgets

I have another wxWidgets question regarding events and focus.

I have already looked at the tutorials and this old question here but I am still running into problems [C++ Event (Focus) Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679979/c-event-focus-handling)

Basically I have a dialog with two wxTextCtrl elements and a Button.
What I would like to achieve is, that when I click on button it needs to tell me which of the two elements previously had the focus.

In the constructor of my Dialog I created all the elements and then connected them to the eventhandler like this: `Ttop->Connect(TOP,wxEVT_KILL_FOCUS,(wxObjectEventFunction)&UI_ADDENTRY::hasfocus);
Tbottom->Connect(BOTTOM,wxEVT_KILL_FOCUS,(wxObjectEventFunction)&UI_ADDENTRY::hasfocus);`

then there is the eventhandler that safes the id into focus

```
void UI_ADDENTRY::hasfocus(wxFocusEvent& event){
    focus= event.GetId();
    event.Skip();}
```

however when i try to access focus in the Button function it always tells me: 0 instead of TOP or BOTTOM / the ids that I gave the textcontrols

```
void UI_ADDENTRY::OnRecord(wxCommandEvent &event){
     wxString tmp;
     tmp << this->focus;
     wxMessageBox(tmp);}
```

What am I doing wrong? is there another way of finding out which of the two textbox has been in focus last?

Thank you

Comment: Couldn't you just check `Ttop->HasFocus()` and `Tbottom->HasFocus()` in your button click handler?

Comment: I tried that initially... like that right if(Ttop->HasFocus())
    {
         wxMessageBox("TOP");
    }  but it doesn't seem every to be true

Comment: Clicking a button would remove focus from the wxTextCtrl. If it sets up a race condition that would give reason for it to only sometimes return true.

Comment: Yes you are right. The FindFocus() will only return the ID of the button that I clicked, just wondering what the solution to this might be - surely I can't be the first one to have to deal with this - but google doesn't help a bit / the documentation of wxWidgets is not clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

The most fool proof way is to catch `EVT_SET_FOCUS` in your text controls and remember the last one that received it. This is not more difficult than what you are doing but should work without problems.

FWIW `EVT_KILL_FOCUS` can't, unfortunately, be consistently implemented on all platforms, in particular GTK+ doesn't give any information about the window focus is being lost to.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I already tried that as well. I have an int id; as a member of my class. Then I wrote this in the eventhandler:   hasfocus(wxFocusEvent& event){ this->id = event.GetId(); but id is always 0
    event.Skip();}

Comment: `event.GetId()` is not the same as `id` which is the member of your class... Use `GetEventObject()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In think u mean event.GetWindow().GetId(). Though I'm not sure how ur casting from int to string.